# .net IIS web server localhost

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2012, iis-7, iis-8

I am new in .net and visual studio.
when I have tried to configure IIS web server in my local machine.

Its running in my system using

URL :- `http://localhost:8080`   ------------ IS IIS 8

But at the same time in mt colleagues system its running using

URL :- `http://localhost/`             ---------- IS IIS 7

Is it something i need to change and host setting ..

Using command --

```
inetmgr
```

or

```
host setting etc
```

***Is it fine for my dev environment setup ??***

Thanks !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Open the Internet Information Service (IIS) Manager** and click on the '**Sites**' menu item on the left. You should see a list of sites that are running on your local installation of IIS. Right click the website whose port you want to change and select '**Bindings...**'.

To have your website run on `http://localhost/` you simply need to change the port in the bindings to port 80.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it fine for my dev environment setup?

Yes.